# How to use Sizzle CSS selector engine?

Tags: sizzle

I don't know how to use Sizzle so how can i use it?

Please provide me some example code.

Thanks,
jakobaindreas11

P.S. I always do questions like these

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation

Comment: there's no examples in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, all you need to know is this:

```
Sizzle("selector");
```

Sizzle supports almost all CSS3 selectors.